# Problem with citation insertion?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I hoping someone can help me with what I am sure is a noob problem. I am simply trying to insert a citation from BibDesk into a LaTeX document. My MWE looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\section{test}
test cite should be here: \cite{brown08}.

\bibliography{cvpubs.bib}

\end{document}
```

My bib file is called `cvpubs.bib` and is in the same directory as the above MWE LaTeX document. The `cvpubs.bib` file looks like this:

```
@article{brown08,
    Author = {Seth Brown and Michael Cole and Albert Erives},
    Date-Added = {2011-10-22 21:01:18 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2011-10-22 21:57:01 +0000},
    Journal = {BMC Genomics},
    Keywords = {evolution, myc},
    Month = {September},
    Number = {442},
    Rating = {5},
    Read = {1},
    Title = {Evolution of the holozoan ribosome biogenesis regulon},
    Volume = {9},
    Year = {2008}}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: The argument to `\bibliography` shouldn't have the extension: try `\bibliography{cvpubs}`

Comment: Could you further describe, what is not working. Did you execute `latex`, `bibtex`, `latex`, `latex` in that sequence? @egreg: The MWE works on my computer, even though it claims `Database file #1: cvpubs.bib.bib`. Strange...

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've tried compiling with latex, pdflatex and xelatex.

Comment: Did you run `bibtex` as well as (pdf/xe)latex? If you don't run bibtex once, you'll just be stuck with warnings about undefined references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\begin{filecontents*}{bibentry-example-02.bib}
@Book{abramowitz,
 author    = "Milton {Abramowitz} and Irene A. {Stegun}",
 title     = "Handbook of Mathematical Functions with
              Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables",
 publisher = "Dover",
 year      =  1964,
 address   = "New York",
 edition   = "ninth Dover printing, tenth GPO printing"
}
@article{brown08,
    Author = {Seth Brown and Michael Cole and Albert Erives},
    Date-Added = {2011-10-22 21:01:18 +0000},
    Date-Modified = {2011-10-22 21:57:01 +0000},
    Journal = {BMC Genomics},
    Keywords = {evolution, myc},
    Month = {September},
    Number = {442},
    Rating = {5},
    Read = {1},
    Title = {Evolution of the holozoan ribosome biogenesis regulon},
    Volume = {9},
    Year = {2008}}
\end{filecontents*}
\nobibliography*  
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
This will give you a full entry (bibentry is used for that) :\\
\bibentry{abramowitz}. 
Use this for citations \cite{abramowitz}\cite{brown08}
\bibliography{bibentry-example}
\end{document}
```

The `bibentry` package is normally used to quote full entries. For this you need to issue the command `bibentry`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Open the .bib file you are using for your references directly from the folder it is located in (as opposed to opening it from bibdesk or 'recent').
- have you saved the recent changes you made to bibdesk?
- typeset Latex, BibTex, Latex, Latex in the Chapter.tex document you have the citations in, as well as in the main thesis.tex document used to compile it all.
- on the thesis console, choose 'Trash Aux Files'. Then recompile a few times as mentioned above. This will generate the citations anew. Works well when files have been transferred.